# create multiple notification from an array using notification gem

Tags: arrays, ruby, notifications, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an employee array.

```
employees = TeamEmployee.where(:team_id => business.team_id).pluck(:employee_id)
```

I want to create notification for each employee using the notification gem which I have already installed in my app

My loop is as follows.

```
nex = business.next_member
employees.each do |emp|
  note = Notification.create(notify_type: 'create_ticket', actor: 
  ticket.assignee, user: emp.id, target: ticket, acceptance:true, 
  message: "#{ticket.title} for Room #{ticket.room.location} has been 
  created. Do you accept?" ) if nex.blank?
  accept_event = AcceptanceEvent.create(business_id: 
  business.id,notification_id: note.id,accepted:false,timer_hours: 
  business.wait_hours,timer_minutes: business.wait_minutes)
end
```

It works fine when I create single notification of the array index.

Can anyone suggest how I can build the array loop to send notification to each index of an array?

Comment: You mean [Enumerable#each_with_index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index) or [Array#each_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index)?

Comment: yeah like i have created this employee array and under notification.create user i want to add the employee array index using a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out the answer, i just had to call that user from user table using the employee array index before i could assign it to notification user attribute

```
employees.each do |emp|
    user = User.where('id = ?', emp)[0]
    note = Notification.create(notify_type: 'create_ticket', actor: 
    ticket.assignee, user: user, target: ticket, acceptance:true, 
    message: "#{ticket.title} for Room #{ticket.room.location} has been 
    created. Do you accept?" )
    accept_event = AcceptanceEvent.create(business_id: 
    business.id,notification_id: note.id,accepted:false,timer_hours: 
    business.wait_hours,timer_minutes: business.wait_minutes)
end
```